# Error: experiments:enablewebframeworks is not a Firebase command

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Upgraded firebase to version 11.15.0 as described here

https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/10/whats-new-at-Firebase-Sumit-2022

```
==> firebase --version
11.15.0
```

Ran

```
==> firebase experiments:enablewebframeworks
```

Got error

```
Error: experiments:enablewebframeworks is not a Firebase command
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a documentation error. There must be a space between the enable & webframeworks

Try to run :

```
firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
```

Instead of :

```
firebase experiments:enablewebframeworks
```

I tried with `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` and was able to execute the command successfully.

You can refer this [github link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools).